# PHP how can i get my csv table to show correctly?

Tags: php, csv

Hi i have this problem that my code can't read my numbers correctly. the file im trying to read is a .csv file seperated by commas. any help is appreciated.
i havent been able to find anything that does exacly as i needed yet, it works if i replace the , with . but i need it to be , for my project.

```
<?php
// inkludere vores footer hvis logget ind
if ($user->is_loggedin() == true) {
    // File selector
    $path = "./assets/csv"; 

    $latest_ctime = 0;
    $latest_filename = '';    

    $d = dir($path);
    while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
    $filepath = "{$path}/{$entry}";
    // could do also other checks than just checking whether the entry is a file
        if (is_file($filepath) && filectime($filepath) > $latest_ctime) {
            $latest_ctime = filectime($filepath);
            $latest_filename = $entry;
        }
    }

    // table start
    echo'<h1 class="text-center">CSV Table</h1>';
    echo'<h6 class="text-center">'.$latest_filename.'</h6>';
    echo '<table id="example" class=" table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">';
    echo'<tbody>';

    $f = fopen("$path/$latest_filename", "r");

    while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {

            $row = $line[0];    // We need to get the actual row (it is the first element in a 1-element array)

            $cells = explode(";",$row);
            echo '<tr>';
            foreach ($cells as $cell) {
                echo '<td>' .htmlspecialchars($cell, ENT_COMPAT). '</td>';

            }
            echo '</tr>';
    }
    fclose($f);
    echo'</tbody>';
    echo '</table>';
}
```

the table Looks like in excel

https://gyazo.com/49e8b16d369b1fa61496601952ca953b

and here is how it looks on my site

https://gyazo.com/b271c3a221587b2e0c6b7ee4cebd6bdb
From what i have read, the reason i get these errors is because i need UTF-8, to be able to read my language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer myself... after a long time of testing none stop, i found this answer

// File selector
        $path = "./assets/csv";

```
    $latest_ctime = 0;
    $latest_filename = '';    

    $d = dir($path);
    while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
    $filepath = "{$path}/{$entry}";
    // could do also other checks than just checking whether the entry is a file
        if (is_file($filepath) && filectime($filepath) > $latest_ctime) {
            $latest_ctime = filectime($filepath);
            $latest_filename = $entry;
        }
    }


    // table start
    echo'<h1 class="text-center">CSV Table</h1>';
    echo'<h6 class="text-center">'.$latest_filename.'</h6>';
    echo '<table id="example" class=" table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">';
    echo'<tbody>';

    $f = fopen("$path/$latest_filename", "r");

    while (($line = fgetcsv($f, 1000, ";")) !== false) {

            $row = $line[0];    // We need to get the actual row (it is the first element in a 1-element array)

            // $cells = explode(";",$row);
            echo '<tr>';
            foreach ($line as $cell) {
                echo '<td>' .htmlspecialchars($cell, ENT_COMPAT). '</td>';

            }
            echo '</tr>';
    }
    fclose($f);
    echo'</tbody>';
    echo '</table>';
 }
```

hope someone could use this, what i have noticed with this solution is that, i think the `while (($line = fgetcsv($f, 1000, ";")) !== false) {` . ive tested it and it could get over 10000 lines. Anyways what i found out saves someone some time. I for sure could have used it.